# software for sharing data through URL (HTTP/HTTPS)

Tags: http, https, url, file-server

do you know about software, which can provide sharing files or folders through generated URL links? Software, which I can implement on my own server? Something like guest links on Sharepoint or sharing data from Google Drive through generated links etc... But it's not necessarily to have web frontend to upload and manage files. I can manage that on server directly. I know only about HFS (http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/), which has few drawbacks... Thank you

Comment: You could use something like [owncloud](https://owncloud.org/). But by the sound of it, that's too much overhead?

Comment: Yes, I know about Own Cloud, but I think, that implementing own cloud for one quite simple task seems to be a little bit overkill. And I don't know, how Own Cloud stores data, but I like the HFS idea, because you can have one folder shared as network share, shared through FTP and also through URL. You don't duplicate data.